# PyTerrier - Assigning parameter values to non-standard models

Tags: python, java, information-retrieval

I am trying to use PyTerrier to conduct information retrieval experiments.There are several weighting models implemented in the original Java code and in the original Terrier documentation - http://terrier.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/terrier/matching/models/package-summary.html

However, I am unable to tune and assign parameter values for models mentioned in the Java documentation but not in the PyTerrier docs:

```
dfr = pt.BatchRetrieve(index, wmodel="DFR_BM25", controls={"c.0":10, "c.1":0},metadata=["docno",'text'], num_results=100)
```

For example, here I am unable to set the control properties/parameters for the DFR_BM25 model. The results of this retrieval does not change with changing values of 'c.0' or 'c.1'. The documentation does not state what each model's parameters are, except for the standard ones like BM25.